# Getting information from two column, not getting duplicate id

Tags: sql

Hello I have a table A like this:

| Id | email | departument | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `abc@hmail.com` | XX | 2022-11-04 |
| 2 | `def@hmail.com` | BB | 2022-12-04 |
| 3 | `abc@hmail.com` | CC | 2023-02-05 |
| 4 | `ghi@hmail.com` | DD | 2022-10-04 |

I have a table B like this:

| email, | date, | reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `abc@hmail.com` | 2022-11-15 | debt |
| `abc@hmail.com` | 2023-02-20 | yyy |
| `mnn@hmail.com` | 2022-12-04 | no |
| `ter@hmail.com` | 2022-09-04 | tt |

I need to create a new table that inserts into new table the A.Id, A.email. A.created_date, B.reason when I found the same email in A e B and the quarter(created_date) in A is the same in quarter(date) B

I am trying using join but I am getting a duplicated a.id. once I am joining using the email column.

My code is more or less this:

```
Insert into C

FROM a
INNER b ON a.email = b.email
AND A.quarter=b.quarter and a.year=b.year
```

Is there any way to not have duplicate id?

Thanks

Comment: please tag with database, and show your SQL

Comment: I did, I add more or less my code

Comment: Hi - “more or less my code” is not the same as showing the actual SQL you are running

Comment: what database is this??? Please tag accordingly, and show a [mcve], not "more or less".  Take the [tour] and read [ask], please.

Answer (score 1):

**ORACLE**:
One way to do it is like here:

```sql
Select  a. ID, a.E_MAIL, a.DEPARTMENT, b.REASON
From    tbl_a a
Inner Join  tbl_b b ON( b.E_MAIL = a.E_MAIL And To_Char(b.A_DATE, 'Q/yyyy') = To_Char(a.CREATED_DATE, 'Q/yyyy') )
```

...with your sample data

```sql
WITH
    tbl_a (ID, E_MAIL, DEPARTMENT,  CREATED_DATE) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'abc@hmail.com', 'XX', To_Date('2022-11-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'def@hmail.com', 'BB', To_Date('2022-12-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'abc@hmail.com', 'CC', To_Date('2023-02-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'ghi@hmail.com', 'DD', To_Date('2022-10-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_b (E_MAIL, A_DATE, REASON) AS
        (
            Select 'abc@hmail.com', To_Date('2022-11-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'debt' From Dual Union All
            Select 'abc@hmail.com', To_Date('2023-02-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyy' From Dual Union All
            Select 'mnn@hmail.com', To_Date('2022-12-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'no' From Dual Union All
            Select 'abc@hmail.com', To_Date('2022-09-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'tt' From Dual 
        )
```

... the result should be:

```sql
        ID E_MAIL        DEPARTMENT REASON
---------- ------------- ---------- ------
         1 abc@hmail.com XX         debt   
         3 abc@hmail.com CC         yyy
```

...

```sql
Insert Into your_table (ID, E_MAIL, DEPARTMENT, REASON) -- put your table name and appropriate column names 
Select  a. ID, a.E_MAIL, a.DEPARTMENT, b.REASON
From    tbl_a a
Inner Join  tbl_b b ON( b.E_MAIL = a.E_MAIL And To_Char(b.A_DATE, 'Q/yyyy') = To_Char(a.CREATED_DATE, 'Q/yyyy') )
```